# I'm new to node.js, and I'm working on getting a pie chart working

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I'm trying to get a pie chart. However, it isn't working too well. The page is completely blank.

I'm using node.js. I have chart.js installed though npm. I run this html on my ejs file, and it is just a blank page.

```
<code>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

     <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>    
            var data = [
                {
                    value: 300,
                    color:"#F7464A",
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                    label: "Red"
                },
                {
                    value: 50,
                    color: "#46BFBD",
                    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                    label: "Green"
                },
                {
                    value: 100,
                    color: "#FDB45C",
                    highlight: "#FFC870",
                    label: "Yellow"
                }
            ]

            var pieOptions = {
                segmentShowStroke : false,
                animateScale : true
            }

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, pieOptions);
        </script>       
  </body>
</html>    
</code>
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow this script http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read too deeply into your code but I noticed that you have your node.js code in the head of the file. Unfortunately, node.js cannot be executed in the browser, but is used for server side implementation of code. What does your console say?

Comment: On the console, I have two get statements. One gets the website. The other get is /node_modules/chart.js/Chart.min.js

Comment: I meant the console in your browser. Looking at the docs of the link you sent I noticed that the file uses a require, which isn't allowed in the browser. You'll need to use something like browserify or the docs you linked had a note on browser support.

Comment: I see what you re talking about. I'm getting a 404 on the chart. I can't seem to link it in Node.

Comment: I put it in the controller, but I get a window not defined in Chart.js. It won't run for me to get to the webpage. return window.requestAnimationFrame ||

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do.

I copied the Charts.min.js file from the node_modules to the public folder.

Other than that, I have the canvas at the top. Also, I had to change the:

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

to

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');